# MS Access VBA EXCEL.EXE not terminating after .quit and = nothing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm running code which opens a user provided spreadsheet. It just brings in the first column excluding the header. running the code once works as expected except it leaves the EXCEL.EXE instance open at the end. I've read several questions having this similar problem, all the answers surround finding any object which was not quit/closed and then set to nothing. I do this for every object in my code and even have error checking which catches if it doesn't complete and to quit and clear the objects. On the second run of the code after the EXCEL.EXE doesn't close it throws a "(1004) Application-defined or Object Defined error" on `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` anyone know why that is?
any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub SplitImports()
Dim StringVar As Variant
Dim strLn As String

'Asks user for Filepath
StringVar = InputBox("Please enter the file path for your list", "Import", "H:\FNMA_WFDC")

'Ends Function if no input or cancel is detected
MsgBox (StringVar)
If (StringVar = vbNullString) Then
    MsgBox ("No input, Please try again")
    Quittracker = True
    Exit Sub
End If

'Scrubs outer quotes if present
StringVar = Replace(StringVar, Chr(34), "", 1, 2)

'Creates the object to check the file
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
MsgBox ("Got Passed the FSO Object")

'Checks that our file exists, exits if not
If (Not FSO.FileExists(StringVar)) Then
    MsgBox ("File does not exist, try again")
    Quittracker = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Set FSO = Nothing

Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xlWrk As Workbook 'Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Long
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
MsgBox ("Dimmed the excel objects")
xlApp.Visible = False

On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

Set xlWrk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(StringVar) 'opens the excel file for processing
MsgBox ("objects are set")

With xlWrk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "@"
    MsgBox (.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    'walks through the excel sheet to the end and inserts the lines below the headerline into the database
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert Into Split_List(Criteria) values('" & .Cells(i, 1).Text & "')"
    Next i

End With
MsgBox ("About to Clear and close the objects")

'closes the workbook and quits the application
xlWrk.Saved = True
xlWrk.Close
Set xlWrk = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

MsgBox ("End of the import sub")
Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    xlWrk.Saved = True
    xlWrk.Close
    Set xlWrk = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    MsgBox ("(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description    
    Quittracker = True
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: Are you running your code from `Access`?

Comment: yeah this is a sub in a form class

Comment: Both instances of `Rows.Count` need to be `.Rows.Count`

Comment: Drop `xlWrk.Saved = True` from the code. Instead use `xlWrk.Close True` and then test if things work.

Comment: @Rory That worked. is that the difference between implicit and explicit referencing?

Comment: Yep! Implicit causes all sorts of problems. Also, not sure why you late bound the application object when you clearly have a reference set.

Comment: apologies i'm new to some of the terminology. that would be `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application` vs `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application`

Comment: Nope! To really latebind, you need to remove the reference altogether. If your code does not compile then it's not really late-bind. BTW, that's an easy way to catch all accidentals `Rows` where there should be `.Rows` and so forth.

Comment: Try splitting up some of the chained object accesses like `xlApp.Workbooks.Open(StringVar)` to get references to the intermediate objects.  Excel's COM server tends to leak reference counts when you don't do this.